# MEDIA_TYPE_DOCUMENT was added in Android API level 30, how to get all documents on Android < 30

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to get all the documents from android device, the solution I found is following but it works for Android API 30 or newer devices.

```
 val musicUri: Uri =
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")

    val projection = arrayOf(
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, 
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, 
        MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, 
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH
    )

    val selection = (MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
            + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_DOCUMENT)

    val musicCursor =
        context.contentResolver.query(
            musicUri,
            projection,
            selection,
            null,
            "${MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED} DESC",
            null
        )
```

and then traversing through the cursor I was able to get all the documents but when it comes to android 29 or less, Android studio complains that the  `MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE_DOCUMENT` was added in Android 30. Hence it is not working as expected on < 30

Can anyone here tell me how can I get all the documents on Android running API <30.

Thank you

Comment: Well.. then what? You cannot use it then.

Comment: Running it on API<30 returns nothing.

Comment: You should not run it then obviously.

Comment: Yes, but then what is the alternative? I need to get all the documents on the phone

Comment: You did not tell what you get if you dont use it.

Comment: Don't use what exactly, the selection?